# Why would a web request that is valid in browser return 404 error from Android?

Tags: android, google-api

I am writing an app to query the Google shopping api. Using the request below with a valid api key returns me the results I'm expecting in a browser but not from an Android device. Why would I get a 404 not found error when sending the request through the HttpClient but the same url in a browser works?

API Call:

http://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?restrictBy=gtin%3A010343876415&key=API_KEY&country=US&alt=json

Thanks

Comment: Well it could be a number of reasons, when I click your link, first thing I notice is: SSL is required to perform this operation.
Are you using SSL in your calls? Is your header being built correctly? Post your code that builds the header.

Comment: I am not setting a header, and I am using https just forgot I changed it to see if that was the problem. Same result with https set. The code I am using to make the request is: 

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url_string);    
 String response = http_connect.execute(request, new BasicResponseHandler());

Where http_connect is an already initialized HttpClient object, I use this for other calls as well so it is working. Do I need to set some extra header information?

Comment: I'm guessing so? What does the Google shopping API say? Can you provide a link to the documentation you have been reading to give us a better idea of what your trying to do?

Comment: Well here is the documentation if you are interested http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html. I got it to work by switching the request type to a HttpGet instead of HttpPost. Still not sure why this would make a 404 error come back. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Good :). Ya I see that a lot of the requests are GET's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in my comment.

The documentation for the api is at code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html. I got it to work by switching the request type to a HttpGet instead of HttpPost. Still not sure why this would make a 404 error come back.